# Mvc3 custom event hooks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, events

I have a Mvc3-Project where I want to register to custom event hooks.

So that I can register to an event like "User logon". I do not want to do it in the controller, because there is a business logic behind it in an other project.

So in my Mvc3-Project I want to write some classes that will have the code that has to be executed when a User is loged on. But how do I register these classes (or an instance of them) to the event. Is it a good idea to use reflection an search for all classes inherited from a special base class, or is there an other smarter way?

So again, I do not want to monitor the action that is called, I want that the business logic triggers some classes in my Mvc3-Project.

Comment: Do you just want to trap the logon event, or do you also want to affect things after (or before) login?  Also, what role do you see for the "special base class" for which you would search via reflection?

Comment: I want to affect things after login. In my controller action I call a login method in my business logic. In the Buisness logic there is an event "OnUserLogon". In my mvc project I now want to register to that event. But the problem is, that html is stateless, so I am thinking about to write an interface or baseclass to find all classes that have to register to the event

Comment: Are you using an inversion of control container?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
As Chris points out in the comments below, MVC3 is stateless, meaning that with this solution you would have to resubscribe for these events on every request. This is probably not a very good solution for MVC.

---

Have you considered an global event service?

Rough example:

```
class Example : IEventReceiver
{
    public void Init()
    {
        EventService.Subscribe("Logon", this);
    }

    private void OnEvent(string eventName)
    {
        // Do logon stuff here.
    }
}
```

You would need to create the `EventService` class, which might be a singleton or service. It might have interface similar to the following:

```
public interface IEventService
{
    void Subscribe(string eventName, IEventReceiver receiver);
    void Unsubscribe(string eventName, IEventReceiver receiver);
    void DispatchEvent(string eventName);
}

public interface IEventReceiver
{
    void OnEvent(string eventName);
}
```

Comment: I am still thinking about your solution. The main problem is, that mvc3 is stateless, so I have to register the events everytime a page loads.

Comment: That's a very good point. This is probably not a good solution then.